# Do action after render() method is completed

Tags: slickgrid

I need to do some action when `render()` method finished its work and appended all HTML elements to DOM.
How to subscribe to `onRenderEnds` event (there is no such event)?
Can I write my own event outside of slickgrid code and attach it to `render()` method?

---

There are some events `"onScroll", "onViewportChanged"` but they happened before `render()` finished (in some cases).

---

Update:
I write formatter for column:

```
formatter: function(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext){
    return "<div class='operationList' data-my='" + myData + "'></div>";            
}
```

When grid rendered (applying my formatter) i need to go through all `".operationList" divs` and convert them to other constructions (based on `data-my` attribute). I need to replace `".operationList" divs` with a complex structure with event handlers.

Comment: @Tin, see my question update.

Comment: @Tin: I have a similar problem since I want to style <select> elements using the jQuery.selectBox() plugin. I realize that I could have the formatter emit the proper HTML and write the event handlers myself but since the plugin is there and works fine I'd rather not. What I'd need to is to call $grid.find('select').selectBox() after render() has completed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic answer is DON'T !
What you are proposing is a very bad design and goes against the core principles and architecture of SlickGrid.

You will end up doing a lot of redundant work and negating most of the performance advantages of SlickGrid.  The grid will create and remove row DOM nodes on the fly as you scroll and do it either synchronously or asynchronously depending on which one suits best at the time.  If you must have rich interactive content in the cells, use custom cell renderers and delegate all event handling to the grid level using its provided events such as onClick.  If the content of the cell absolutely cannot be created using renderer, use async post-rendering - http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example10-async-post-render.html.  Even so, the grid content should not have any event listeners registered directly to the DOM nodes.

To address @magiconair's comment, you really shouldn't render a whole SELECT with all its options and event handlers until a cell switches into edit mode.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. I haven't thought of that.

Answer (score 9):

To answer on my own comment I've come up with the following **hack**. It may not be pretty but it seems to work.

Add the following line to the `render()` method just below `renderRows(rendered);`

```
function render() {
    ...
    renderRows(rendered);
    trigger(self.onRenderCompleted, {}); // fire when rendering is done
    ...
}
```

Add a new event handler to the public API:

```
"onRenderCompleted":            new Slick.Event(),
```

Bind to the new event in your code:

```
grid.onRenderCompleted.subscribe(function() {
    console.log('onRenderCompleted');
});
```

Comment: Your solution is very good. There is only one drawback: it is necessary to go into the library code and edit it. What happens if you want to update slickGrid library? You will need to copy your code into a new code library. This is bad. As you said - a "hack".
But this is the best way I know. Now.

Comment: What you could do is to fork the code on github and maintain your own changes. Then when you want to update the code you pull the changes from the master repo and your changes should be merged automatically.

Comment: This trigger(self.onRenderCompleted, {}); should really be at the very end of the render method - because render is not completed until the method has finished.

Comment: BTW: I had to resort to this solution as well as my scaffolding was dependent on a a somewhat customized slickGrid.

Comment: Triggers also when [] items are passed to the grid (so no data)