# onRendered callback

Tags: slickgrid

I need to implement a sought of `onRendered()` event that would ensure all of the grid is rendered before I do something, which is to `.hide()` it. My gaol is to have a `.hide()` and `.show()` button attached to the `div` the grid resides in, with the default status set at hidden. The problem is that at the point in which *my* script executes the initial `.hide()`, the grid is not fully created yet by the grid.js script. I would rather not do any delay loop. Much rather have a callback.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks
Pat

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224661/do-action-after-render-method-is-completed?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work without a callback. I have a SlickGrid app where I show and hide the grid in response to UI events. The grid exists as soon as it is instantiated (with `new Slick.Grid`) and can be manipulated with the `.hide()`and `.show()` methods.

I did find one catch though...

If you create the `div` tag with `display: none` (so it is initially hidden) the grid columns do not initialise properly. To workaround this I create the div tag with `visibility: hidden` and remove this style before using the `.hide()`and `.show()` methods.

My code looks roughly like this:

```
  <div id="mygrid" style="visibility: hidden"></div>

  $grid = $("#mygrid")

  grid = new Slick.Grid($grid, gridData, gridColumns, gridOptions);

  // Hide grid by default, remembering to remove the visibility style
  $grid.hide();
  $grid.css("visibility", "visible");

  // You can now show and hide the grid using normal jQuery methods
  $grid.show();
  $grid.hide();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The slick grid has implemented an event onRendered event [github source](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.grid.js#L4165). We can subscribe to this event and make the appropriate use of it.

Comment: we did add that over a year ago but it should be noted that we are talking about the [6pac/SlickGrid](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.grid.js#L5957) fork (not the original repo)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).